GitLab Runner Registration Fails Due to TLS Error: "certificate relies on legacy Common Name field, use SANs instead"
I am running a GitLab instance on an EC2 instance located in a private subnet on AWS. The EC2 instance is accessible only through SSM (AWS Systems Manager) and OpenVPN, ensuring that the environment is secured and isolated from public access.
Environment Details:
EC2 Instance: Running on a private subnet (no direct internet access).
Access: Restricted to SSM and OpenVPN.
GitLab: Installed and configured on this EC2 instance.
I’m trying to register a GitLab Runner on this GitLab instance, but I’m encountering a TLS error during the runner verification step. The specific error message is as follows:
ERROR: Verifying runner... failed
runner=5j9he2QPz status=couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab.olive0-druwa.com/api/v4/runners/verify: Post "https://gitlab.olive0-druwa.com/api/v4/runners/verify": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate relies on legacy Common Name field, use SANs instead
PANIC: Failed to verify the runner.

Steps Taken:
I generated a self-signed SSL certificate with OpenSSL, including the SAN (Subject Alternative Name) field.
The SSL certificate and key are correctly placed in /etc/gitlab/ssl/ as gitlab.olive0-druwa.com.crt and gitlab.olive0-druwa.com.key.
The gitlab.rb file is configured with the following settings:
ruby
external_url "https://gitlab.olive0-druwa.com"
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.olive0-druwa.com.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.olive0-druwa.com.key"
I ran sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure to apply the changes.
Issue:
Despite the above configuration, when attempting to register the GitLab Runner using the following command, I get the TLS verification error:

gitlab-runner register --url https://gitlab.olive0-druwa.com --token YOUR_TOKEN_HERE
The error suggests that the certificate relies on a legacy Common Name (CN) field and that SANs should be used instead, but the certificate already includes a SAN.

Question:
How can I resolve this TLS error and successfully register my GitLab Runner? Is there something I am missing in the configuration, or could this be related to the way the certificate was generated? Additionally, could the private subnet configuration and restricted access via SSM and OpenVPN be influencing this issue?
If there's a way to simply ignore this issue, please let me know as well.
